# .htaccess only allow access and redirect to root index.php for only one directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm getting some troubles with htaccess in my new php project . I couldn't find any solutions so I ask here , hope someone will help me out.

1 . What I need :

On root , urls pointing to existing files and folders are not accessible , except     /Public/ and all its folders and files ( only /Public/ is allowed to access ) . Urls pointing to files and folders which are not existings will be redirected to **root index.php**. /Public/ is redirected to **root index.php** too , folders and files inside it are not ( direct access ).

2 . What I have tried and are not working :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Public
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index\.php$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [F,L,NC]
 RewriteBase /Public/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Public
 RewriteRule . - [F,L,NC]
 RewriteBase /Public/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [F,L,NC]
 RewriteBase /Public/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You are on linux? check if apache user have access to files other than public folder

Comment: I'm doing my project on windows . But I will test it with some linux environment when it's completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^public /index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying . But that returns 403 Forbidden for all the urls

Comment: Thank you sir. But it still results in 403 for root folder and 404 for non-existing files and folders :(

Comment: I guess your requirement is not clear. Didn't you want anything this is not public to be blocked?

Comment: I can explain my requirements here : My file structure is Root{ "index.php","Some folders containing class files" , "Plugins folder" , "Public folder" } and I need to allow accesses only inside "Public folder" and move all other accesses to index.php inside Root

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: oops . My bad . Sorry I forgot to do so :D