# Codeigniter htaccess redirect to index.php only on root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have structure directory in Codeigniter like this

```
/application
/assets
/system
.htaccess
index.php
test.php
```

And this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

What i want is, if user access any other PHP or HTML file except index.php, it'll be redirected to index.php. For example, if someone access test.php, it'll be redirected to index.php. But i want it only work for root directory and not effected to other directory

I've already try from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025312/htaccess-only-allow-access-and-redirect-to-root-index-php-for-only-one-director?rq=1) but it didn't work for me

Comment: Not clear your question..

Comment: @HardikPaghdar What i want is, if user access any other PHP or HTML file except index.php, it'll be redirected to index.php. For example, if someone access test.php, it'll be redirected to index.php. But i want it only work for root directory only

Comment: if user is login then access direct url test.php is allow or not ?

Comment: @HardikPaghdar No, he doesn't allow to access test.php or any other file, so user only allow access index.php

Comment: you have to check all controller user are login or not if user login then go any url if user are not login then go to login screen

Comment: @HardikPaghdar this has nothing to do with authentication. He wants every request for any file except the `index.php` in the root directory redirected to `index.php`. In any other directory he does not want this redirection. This is a webserver thing, this has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: @Clemenz Well i think Hardik doesn't understand very well about my question, although i was struggling to explain what i mean and update my question post.

Comment: @HardikPaghdar I think you need to read again about my question :)